# VS Code : Sign In Error :You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-machine-learning-service

In VS Code when i try to run the below command for sign in

[image]

I get below error message and it is not able to login

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy perhaps? Because I see feedback complaining that the extension does not support a proxy: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.azure-account&ssr=false#review-details

Comment: Also seeing this when I have the project opened in [WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/remote-overview) but when opened in Windows it's fine.

Comment: @Peter B Yes, I'm using my office system, so I guess proxy and firewall creating all this mess

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue due to working behind a company proxy. I could solve it by writing the http proxy in the settings (instead of leaving it empty and inheriting from environment variables).

Comment: You are awesome! :D

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - the problem was that my VS code was still remotely connected to my office server via SSH. I killed that connection ("close remote connection") and it allowed me to sign in.

Answer (score 0):

Same exact issue for me, caused (most likely) by my company's proxy blocking the sign-in request. What fixed it was:

1. closing Visual Studio Code (previously opened through code . in WSL in my case);
2. opening Visual Studio Code again directly in Windows;
3. Login to Azure (then finally the browser opened with the login page and I could get in)

Of course your log-in will be saved also when you close VSCode in windows and reopen in WSL.