# VS Code Azure Extension: Infinite loading loop

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, azure-functions

I am using Azure Extensions for developing and deploying function app. When I open the Azure Extension tab, the RESOURCES fold is infinitely loading, without showing the remote subscription tree.
[image]

I tried to log out and log in again, but it gives the error "You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection." Restarting VS Code will just repeat the nightmare.

[image]

I am using my home MacBook and don't have any proxy setup. It worked before but all of a sudden it stopped.

Currently I am totally stuck. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: While not an answer to your real question, I found a workaround to using the VSCode integrations for developing and deploying. The functions CLI let me run locally and deploy pretty seamlessly once I gave up on VSCode for now. Hopefully you can at least be unblocked...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Cmacos%2Cpython%2Cportal%2Cbash
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish

Comment: i ended up setting up the github workflow from the function app, it is not ideal as it costs building time on git, but at least i am not blocked anymore

Comment: actually the CLI is super ! i just used this command and it works like a charm! "func azure functionapp publish <myfunctionappname>"
thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/733#issuecomment-1468239088)

SOLVED for me: Works when updating vscode settings (reload required): "http.systemCertificates": false

Answer (score 0):

Even either of OS (Windows or Mac), I observed the same glitch in my VS Code IDE i.e., sometimes extensions will load slowly related to Azure and below workaround helps me to load it faster):

1. Open the Command Shift Palette in VS Code, available under View Menu or using Shortcut key (`Cmd+Shift+P`)
2. Disable all extensions that are installed in the VS Code.

[image]

3. Restart the VS Code IDE and System also (if possible). Then, you'll not see the Azure Extension on the VS Code Index Bar.

[image]

4. Open VS Code and try enabling all extensions all at once using Command Palette:
   [image]

(OR)

5. You can check by enabling one by one extension by going to Extensions Panel > Click on "Each Extension" > Click on Enable so that you can check the Azure Extension is loading faster and related Services, Applications are loading faster in the Azure Extension Panel.

[image]
[image]

**Note**:

1. Either of the option, it takes a couple of minutes to activate extension and load the Services/Applications in Azure extension panel.
2. If you come by enabling one by one Azure Extensions in VS Code > we can identify which extension is loading the services/applications faster and making other extension slower.

#### Updated Answer:

> You appear to be offline.

Check this GitHub-VSCode Issue [147](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/147) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633916/vs-code-sign-in-error-you-appear-to-be-offline-please-check-your-network-con). Still if you're facing the same issue, you can raise the ticket in the same GitHub Issue [Forum](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92465) of VS Code.

Comment: The issue being described isn’t about slow loading. I’m running into the same thing (as of just a few days ago). Azure resources don’t load at all - even if hours are given - and when attempting to sign in to the azure account the “You appear to be offline” message appears. This solution may work for slow loads, but does not resolve the issue described. I tried this approach and have the same issues

Comment: This is not only about Slow loading. This helps to work extensions faster. For your error "You appear to be offline" - check this GitHub-VSCode Issue [147](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/147) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633916/vs-code-sign-in-error-you-appear-to-be-offline-please-check-your-network-con). Still if you're facing the same issue, you can raise the ticket in the same GitHub Issue Forum of VS Code.

Comment: hi @HariKrishna, i tried your solution but it didn't solve my issue, the resources tab still doesn't load , i also checked the two issue links you posted, i don't think it is related to my case as i am not behind any proxy, and the proxy settings are default. I will raise a ticket in the forum for further help

Comment: Sure, Update the GitHub Issue Link in the Comments or in my Answer so that it would be helpful to the community.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azureresourcegroups/issues/609 link attached

Comment: Check this [comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/733#issuecomment-1468239088) from the related GitHub Issue that may resolve your issue.