# Sign in to Azure via VS Code fails, shows "You appear to be offline" error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I am trying to Sign in to Azure through Azure Account extension, and I am getting the below error:

```
You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection.
```

After looking at the extension logs, I see the below lines repeating as the extension is continuously trying to sign me in:

```
Attempting to reach URL "https://login.microsoftonline.com/"...
certificate has expired
```

Here is all the things I have tried so far:

- Use `Azure: Sign in with Device Code...`: Gives me the same error.
- Set `"http.systemCertificates": false` in Settings: Done, no effect.
- Check proxy settings: I don't have any proxy set up on my VS Code.
- Disable all extensions
- Re-install extension and VS Code

I am on macOS and using latest version of VS Code and Azure Account extension.
I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue.

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633916/vs-code-sign-in-error-you-appear-to-be-offline-please-check-your-network-con) for the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection. Attempting to reach URL “https://login.microsoftonline.com/” certificate has expired

You need to check settings.json of your azure account configuration and remove any extra configuration.

***You can visit your VS code > File > Preferences > Settings > and Add your Azure Tenant ID for authenticating with your Azure tenant and check settings.json file to validate if your TenantID and Subscription ID is present.***

[image]

***My setting.json has tenantid/subscriptionid appended like below:-***

[image]

***Additionally Sign into your Azure account by method given below:-***

You can sign in to Azure via VS Code in 2 ways:

1.Go to View>Command palette>Azure: Sign in. Then you will navigate to web browser, select your Azure account for Sign in and you will be signed into VS Code.

View>Command palette
[image]

Azure: Sign in
[image]

2.Go to Sign in to sync settings> Sign in with Microsoft. Then you will navigate to web browser, select your Azure account for Sign in and you will be successfully signed into your Azure account.

Sign in to sync settings: -
[image]

Sign in with Microsoft:
[image]

Select your Azure account :
[image]

The browser look like the below, you can close this.
[image]

I signed in VS code successfully like below:
[image]

Additionally, Try to uninstall the Azure Account extension and install it again and try to log in:-

[image]

Try to add below urls in your terminal for proxy and connect to your azure account again, Refer below:-

```bash
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:8080
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@proxy:8080
```

**Refer here:-**

[Sign in to Azure Account from VS Code - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276651/sign-in-to-azure-account-from-vs-code)

Also, Check if you’re connected to any VPN or corporate LAN, If you have any firewall restrictions, Try to whitelist the - [login.microsoftonline.com](http://login.microsoftonline.com) url from your firewall to log into Azure.

**Refer here:-**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1065925/error-httpsconnectionpool(host-login-microsoftonli

**Also, refer the similar issue in this Github link-**
[“certificate has expired” error when attempting to log in to Azure Stack · Issue #534 · microsoft/vscode-azure-account · GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-azure-account/issues/534)

***In the issue above, The User certificates were restricting the User from signing into Azure from VS code, Try to delete the unwanted certificates rom your utilities in MAC OS and check if the issue gets resolved.***

**Addtional Reference:-**

[azure machine learning studio - VS Code : Sign In Error :You appear to be offline. Please check your network connection - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633916/vs-code-sign-in-error-you-appear-to-be-offline-please-check-your-network-con)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You provided many solutions, some of which I have already had tried. What eventually fixed this for me was probably the "last resort" fix which you mentioned in your answer, too. I initially tried removing the expired user certificates from Keychain Access which didn't solve the problem. I ended up doing a `Reset Default Keychains...`, which is not the best solution because it basically removes all your logins, credentials, etc., though it finally fixed this for me.